# Tex studio not working in Mac

Tags: texstudio, mac

I am using Macbook air. I had Texstudio in my Mac and it was working fine. Yesterday it disappeared suddenly. If I search using spotlight, it is not showing.

I install it from some webpage, then mac was throwing an error "the installation is from unauthorized place so couldnt open". I have deleted the Texstudio icon from Applications folder as it was not working in order to uninstall it.

I just install "MacTex" and I don't know how to use this. Kindly help me with restoring Texstudio in my Macbook.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a Mac issue. Unless you give your Mac specific instructions, it won't open applications that are not from the App Store (and a handful of other places). Here are Apple's instructions about how to get your Mac to open such an application: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/open-a-mac-app-from-an-unidentified-developer-mh40616/mac

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and got it solved. Kindly follow the instruction.

Change these preferences on your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, then click General.

Here a message will appear; kindly allow that message, enabling it to run.